# Providing a specific dependency to a specific client in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to bind two specific implementations of the same interface. One is the regular service, which should be used generally,  the other is a variation of the first, which adds caching. The latter must be provided to only a couple of classes, instead of the generally used one.

I know all about bindings in Guice, including named and annotation bindings, but none of them really fits my scenario. I do not want my client to have to use a specific annotation,  or a string value. The less it knows,  the better. The decision of which dependency to provide to it,  must come from the outside,  i.e from the module.

So, if named and annotation bindings are out,  I am left with binding to a concrete instance. It is a solution, because it will allow me to provide the specific dependency in the constructor of the client,  but still I find it suboptimal.

What would you advise me to do?

Comment: If you want to separate the knowledge of which `Dependency` to use from your `Service`, then I think the best thing to do is use a custom `ServiceProvider implements Provider<Service>` type that passes in the dependencies explicitly, as you suggested.

Comment: This means that my Service would need to know that it expects a provider of some kind, right? I wanted to make it as simple as knowing the interface of the dependency and nothing more

Comment: It's unclear why using binding annotations for the few classes that need caching is problematic. Why wouldn't you want the person reading the code that requires a caching FooFactory to know that the FooFactory caches?

Comment: @NamshubWriter Well, it's simple. Why would my client class even have to know that another component is caching the data? That's the whole point of using IoC in the first place. Taking the composition out of the concerns of the individual components, so you can mix and match them in whatever ways possible. If my component happens to know what to expect, even when it is not a direct dependency, this would make everyone who's using it, wrap a head around the same solution over and over again. It's a no-go. Period.

Comment: The point of IoC is the client doesn't need to find the dependency ("don't call us, we'll call you").  There are plenty of reasons why the client might want to qualify *what* is being injected. Let me ask this a different way: why do some of the classes need to get an instance that is *not* cached?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very similar to one that would require [private modules](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html), except that private module bindings can't conflict with the global bindings in the Injector. It would be tricky to express "this binding applies *everywhere except within this other private module*".

When your constructors can't be annotated to express the deps separately, one way to do this is to manually create your classes (i.e. wrap your constructors). This means your wrappers would need to change whenever the constructors change, but that may not be very problematic.

```
public class CachingModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {}

  // You could also write and bind a full Provider<T>, but this is more concise.
  @Provides FirstClassThatNeedsCaching provideFirst(
      CachingService service, Dep2 dep2) {
    return new FirstClassThatNeedsCaching(service, dep2);
  }

  @Provides SecondInterface provideSecond(CachingService service, Dep3 dep3) {
    return new SecondClassThatNeedsCaching(service, dep3);
  }
}
```